# fbprohet with its 'easter' /'holidays' issues

Tags: python, conda

I know that this **fbprophet** easter problem is a well-documented issue. To temporarily fix this problem, one should import easter from **dateutil** using the line: from `dateutil.easter` import easter.

How do I move from here and then use **fbprophet** module? I am using **jupyter** notebook.

```py
Given my DataFrame, df,
m = Prophet(),
m.fit(df),
```

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has solved this problem with a new (0.6) version. The fix has been pushed to both PyPI and conda forge.

[https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/1293#issuecomment-589832103][1]